# A simple unit test, when run it, get error "No tests found"

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-boot-test

In my springboot project, I don't need to unit test those mvc things but some pure POJO classes.

My pojo class:

```
public class Calculator {

   public int add(int a, int b) {
       return a+b;
   }
}
```

My test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class SimpleTest {
    @Test
    void testIt() {
      Calculator cal = new Calculator();
      int result = cal.add(1, 2);
      assertThat(result).isEqualTo(3);
    }
}
```

I am using intellij IDE. Next to the `void testIt()` line of code on the left, there is a small run arrow, when I click and run the test function , I get failure:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [com.my.calculator.SimpleTest.testIt](filter.includeTestsMatching)
```

Why I get this `No test found` error?

BTW, the dependencies of my project for the test :

```
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core'
```

Comment: any differents if you remove `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`? And are you sure you use the same calculator class? your calculator class is in lower case.

Comment: That was my typo, it is the same calculator class. Removing the annotation doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you check if you have this following part:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try, by the way, for my pojo test, do I need that annotation `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` ?

Comment: This extension will let you, run your tests without, the Spring context will be initialized. What can I see in your tests will be a very good option instead of `@SpringBootTests`

Comment: So, if I understand your comment correctly, you are suggesting me to keep that extension annotation, right?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the spring-boot-starter-test imports a different version of junit, ie jupiter is Junit 5 and I believe spring-boot-starter-test uses Junit 4 so be careful about mixing versions. I have copied the mvn dependency from spring-boot-starter-test below (it uses junit 4).

```
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```